# Making Grails form development DRYer

Tags: grails, groovy, webforms, grails-plugin

When using Grails, the GSP code to render each form field looks something like this:

```
<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="username">Login Name:</label></td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'username', 'errors')}">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="${person.username?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="userRealName">Full Name:</label></td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'userRealName', 'errors')}">
    <input type="text" id="userRealName" name="userRealName" value="${person.userRealName?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="prop">
  <td valign="top" class="name"><label for="passwd">Password:</label></td>
  <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'passwd', 'errors')}">
    <input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="${person.passwd?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Notice that almost exactly the same 5 lines of GSP/HTML code is repeated for each form field. This doesn't seem very DRY to me, and I'm wondering if others have found a better approach?

I've found 2 plugins which attempt to address this problem, the [form helper](http://www.grails.org/plugin/form-helper) and [bean-fields](http://www.grails.org/plugin/bean-fields). If anyone has experience using either of these, I'd be very interested to hear from them. Alternatively, if there are other solutions/plugins, please let me know.

Thanks.
Don

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [bean-field plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/bean-fields).
Your code will become:

```
<bean:withBean beanName="person">
    <bean:field property="username" label="Login Name:"/>
    <bean:field property="userRealName" label="Full Name:"/>
    <bean:field property="passwd" label="Password:"/>
</bean:withBean>
```

Can you find a DRYer solution?

Comment: @sudhir's answer is DRYer, since the Grails Fields plugin will do all of this with a single tag.

Answer (score 8):

For those who read this thread in future - For grails 2.x branch [Grails fields](http://grails.org/plugin/fields) plugin is recommended over bean fields, its actually successor of bean-fields and provides flexibility to override default templates

Comment: I never realised I lived in the future until now :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, bean-fields plugin is very DRY…  your 20 lines can be replaced with one line:

```
<bean:form beanName="person" properties="username, userRealName, passwd”/>
```

(Assuming you have i18n properties set)